# Minimize total distance, k links for each of N points on plane

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, graph-theory

Given *N* points on a plane (*N* is even), is there an efficient algorithm to generate *k* (*k* < *N*) connections from each point to *k* other points where the global distance is minimized?

For example, with *N*=4 and *k*=2 this [optimal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrKzq.png) would be preferred over this [non-optimal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10ZvV.png).

Global distance is the sum of connected distances.  The nodes do not need to be fully connected (islands are fine).

Comment: Sounds like a traveling salesman problem to me. Have you looked at that algorithm?

Comment: @mba12 this is no TSP even for k=2 as there is no requirement to form a single cycle.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios The graph resulting from n knn queries is not symmetric and thus not a solution for this problem. In fact, I am not even sure if the solution is a subset of this graph (if all edges were made symmetric).

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I've updated the question to define global distance and that multiple connected components are allowed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have described is called [Graph Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization) and what you are looking for is a minimum cost k-matching of a graph. You can proceed by reading [Richard P. Anstee, *A polynomial algorithm for b-matchings: An alternative approach*, 1987](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019087901785) which provides a strongly polynomial time algorithm to solve it.